# VScodeからGithub認証できない

Tags: linux, git, vscode, github

VScodeからgithubアカウントで設定共有、privateリポジトリクローンしたいです。

VScode > アカウント > Turn on Setting Sync からGithubアカウント認証しようとしますが、更新のインジケータが回りっぱなしで、Setting syncできません。

以下は成功します。
・LAN内の他端末でgithubログイン
・CLIからgitコマンドで、自身のpublicリポジトリのクローン
・ブラウザ上でVScodeを介さないログイン（github.co.jpからサインイン）

・環境
machine : thinkpad x230i
OS : kali linux, Karnel : 5.15.0-ka
Browser : Chrome, firefox
git : 2.34.1
VScode : 1.63.2

必要な情報あれば更新します。
ご協力をお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

gnome-keyringは入れていますか?
Githubの[Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92972#issuecomment-625751232)のように、

```
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```

で、入れると連携ができるかもしれません。